# Show processed results in flask to user when he logs in

Tags: python, html, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm very new to Flask and don't have much experience in Python.
As required by my project, **I need to do certain processing in the backend (through Python script) using the input given by user and show the end results to the user afterwards, whenever he logs in.**

**A little description as to what my project does** - Whenever the user logs in, he/she enters any Twitter handle in html form and the python script gets certain details regarding that handle (number of similar users, followers, no. of tweets, etc.) and this process takes approximately 5-6 minutes. Currently, I am processing and storing all this data in CSVs and then showing the results in HTML.

Now, I don't want my user to wait for those 5-6 minutes to view the results and thus, want the processed results to be stored in the database so that the user can view them whenever he logs in, say even after 1-2 hours.

How should I implement this in Flask, by using SQLAlchemy? I already have made the database for login screen as below, but don't know how to go about this.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db', echo=True)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():
    error = False
    POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
    POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    s = Session()
    query = s.query(User).filter(User.username.in_([POST_USERNAME]), 
User.password.in_([POST_PASSWORD]))

    data = query.first()
    if data:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        flash('Login success')
        return render_template('test.html')
    else:
        flash('Login failed!')
        return render_template('login.html',error=True)

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session['logged_in'] = False
    return home()
```

The test.html mentioned above takes the twitter handle as input from the user through html form.

Comment: You do not have to initiate a session only when  the route is called, I recommend moving `Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)` and `s=Session()` to the very top of the code right below `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: @Divise thanks for the advice, I'll surely make the changes! Could you help me regarding storing the processed results in the database?

Comment: @Divise Actually, when using vanilla SQLA (as opposed to Flask-SQLA), it's not a good idea to share a single global session instance (`s = Session()`) – in fact in case of SQLite it will not even work, if running the server so that it uses separate threads, and other DB's connections might break as well. Create the `Session` class once, instantiate it in the views. But you really should consider using Flask-SQLAlchemy. It provides better integration with Flask, for example it uses a thread-local session that is cleaned up at the end of a request etc.